# How to map newest records from the list by each id?

Tags: class, salesforce, apex

I have a method in apex class that will get attachments (ContentDocument) from e-mail of case and will add it to another case. There are 2 questions below in order to finish my code:

1. How to create logic to get list of e-mails where I need only the newest e-mail for each case?
2. How can I create logic to get list of srID passed in this method?

Both questions are mentioned in the proper part of the code below:

```
public static void AttFromParenttoClonedCaseList(list<ID>srID){

    list< ContentDocumentLink>  attchlist2=new list< ContentDocumentLink>(); 
    Map<Id, Case> mapCasess = new Map<Id, Case>(); 
    Map<Id, EmailMessage> mapEmail = new map<Id, EmailMessage>();
    Map<Id, EmailMessage> mapemailmessageId = new Map<Id, EmailMessage>();
    List<String> externalIdCases = new List<String>();  
    List<String> casesID = new List<String>(); 
    List<Case> ListCaseNumber = new List<Case>([SELECT ID, External_ID__c From Case WHERE ID IN :srID]);
    
    for (Case mpC : ListCaseNumber){
        mapCasess.put(mpC.id, mpC);
    } 
    
    for (Case Listcase : ListCaseNumber) {  
        externalIdCases.add(Listcase.External_ID__c);
    }     
    List<Case> ListCaseID = new List<Case>([SELECT ID From Case WHERE ID IN :externalIdCases]);    
    
    for (Case listIdcases : ListCaseID) {  
        casesId.add(listIdcases.id);
    }    
    
    Map<id, EmailMessage> listEmailMessage = new Map<id, EmailMessage>([SELECT parentID, ID From EmailMessage WHERE parentID IN :casesId order by parentid, createddate desc]);
    
    \\How to create logic to get list of e-mails where I need only the newest e-mail for each case (base on list listEmailMessage above)?   
    
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contentdocumentId = new List<ContentDocumentLink>([SELECT ID, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :/*list of emailmessages*/]);
    
    for (ContentDocumentLink links : contentdocumentId){
                       
              ContentDocumentLink linkAtt = new ContentDocumentLink(); 
                             
              linkAtt.LinkedEntityId = \\how can I create logic to get list of srID passed in this method?
              linkAtt.ContentDocumentId = links.ContentDocumentId;       
              linkAtt.ShareType = 'V';         
              linkAtt.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
              attchlist2.add(linkAtt);                                            
    }             
    if (attchlist2.size() > 0)                
    insert attchlist2;          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to create logic to get list of e-mails where I need only the
> newest e-mail for each case?

Something like this should be a good start

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject,
    (SELECT Id, FromAddress, ContentDocumentIds
    FROM EmailMessages 
    WHERE Incoming = true 
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
    LIMIT 1)
FROM Case
LIMIT 10
```

It's simpler to treat it as "parent + related list, filtered, sorted" than "give me all emails for this parent, I'll build a Map or something with them, manually loop through them, compare dates to pick most recent...". I haven't worked with Emails for a while so you might need more filters but it's a good start.

> how can I create logic to get list of srID passed in this method?

Not sure I understand. You want to re-link attachments from old case's emails to new case? See if that `ContentDocumentIds` is enough to build new links. If not - loop through results of my query, collect all EmailMessage Ids and query ContentDocumentLinks `WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :emailMessageIds`?

Check if this compiles?

```apex
// I don't really need it as a Map, list seems to be fine. But looks like you wanted Maps so I went with map.
// Map might be useful if External_ID__c is not a lookup.
// If you want a list (or set) of Ids from a query the very easy trick is to do
// Set<Id> myIds = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 5]).keyset();
// Anyway.

// "External_ID__c" is a lookup to Case or something else? Assuming it's just a lookup, bit like "ParentId".
Map<Id, Case> originals = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber, External_ID__c, External_ID__r.CaseNumber,
        (SELECT Id, FromAddress, ContentDocumentIds
        FROM EmailMessages 
        WHERE Incoming = true 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
        LIMIT 1)
    FROM Case
    WHERE Id IN :srId AND External_ID__c != null]);

List<ContentDocumentLink> links = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
for(Case original : originals.values()){
    System.debug('source: ' + original);
    System.debug('target: ' + original.External_ID__r.CaseNumber);
    
    if(!original.EmailMessages.isEmpty()){
        List<String> documentIds = original.EmailMessages[0].ContentDocumentIds;
        for(String i : documentIds){
            links.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
                LinkedEntityId = original.External_ID__c,
                ContentDocumentId = i,
                ShareType = 'V',
                Visibility = 'AllUsers'
            ));
        }
    }
}
insert links;
```

Comment: Hi eyescream, thanks for share information. Your query help me a lot for question 1. For question 2 I really need to re-link attachments from old's case emails to new case. the list of new cases ID are being passed in this method as srID. The query for question 1 is to get emails from old case and after that get proper attachments by using lastest query mentioned in code. The LinkedEntityId should be new case ID to re-link with attachments from old's case emails. My question is how to to match new cases ID along with attachments  from old's case emails where I can insert new re-links.

Comment: I have changed little bit your query and I need to get second ID and pass to list in for. So how may I do it?
  List<Case> listEmailMessage = new List<Case>([SELECT ID, (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessages WHERE Incoming = true ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Case WHERE ID IN :casesId]);
        
        for (Case listIdemail : listEmailMessage) {  
            emailId.add(listIdemail.Id);
        }    
thanks you.

Comment: You might be able to do it all in 1 query, have a look